# Django ORM: Get first instance for each foreignkey

Tags: sql, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

Some Authors might have no Book. Is there a way to get a list or set containing exactly one Book per Author who wrote at least on Book? I'm looking for a solution in one single SQL transaction.

For example, if I have the following entries:

Authors:

- Albert Camus
- Friedrich Nietzsche
- Sigmund Freud

Books:

- Thus Spoke Zarathustra by Nietzsche
- The Myth of Sisyphus by Camus
- The Rebel by Camus

I want a query which returns [Thus Spoke Zarathustra, The Myth of Sisyphus], or [Thus Spoke Zarathustra, The Rebel].

Bonus points of the query returns the books with the lowest `number`.

Comment: Which book does it have to return if there are many ?

Comment: Any book. The best would be to return the one with the lowest `number`, but any book would be fine as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) - for example

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

books = Book.objects.filter(author_id=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('number')
authors = Author.objects.annotate(book_title=Subquery(books.values('title')))

for author in authors:
    print(author.name, author.book_title)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use raw queries. Something like this:

```
query='''
SELECT b1.id, b1.title, b1.author_id, b1.number from Books_book b1, (
    SELECT author_id, min(number) as min_number
    from Books_book
    GROUP BY author_id
) as b2
WHERE b1.author_id=b2.author_id AND b1.number = b2.min_number
'''
books_list = Book.objects.raw(query)[:]
```

Now `books_list` contains one book for each author(with lowest number), as required